# Select from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have table

```
user_task(_id,email,task_id)
```

Table

```
users(_id int, email varchar(50))
```

Table

```
tasks(_id,name)
```

And table

```
subtask(_id,name, task_id)
```

I need two select statements

1. Select all tasks of certain user by email
2. Select subtasks of this user

Don't have experience in sql-joins. so i need some help. thanks in advance

I think this statement will do the job for the 1st statement, but im not sure

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE _id=
(SELECT task_id FROM user_tasks WHERE email='$email')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting all the tasks for a certain email id you need to join `user_tasks` and `tasks`

```
select
ut._id,
ut.email,
ut.task_id,
t.name
from user_task ut
join tasks t on t._id = ut.task_id
where ut.email = 'some email id'
```

Selecting sub-tasks related to the user you need to join all the tables something as

```
select  
ut._id ,
ut.email,
ut.task_id,
t.name as task_name,
st._id as sub_task_id,
st.name as sub_task_name
from subtask st
join tasks t on t._id = st.task_id
join user_task ut on ut.task_id = t._id
where ut.email = 'some email id'
```

**UPDATE** After the question being updated I see that there is `user` table and you are storing emailid to `user_task` , I would recommend to store the userid in the table `user_task` so that if user changes the email id it will not create any issue to the related tables and you just need to join the `user` table to `user_tasks` table using the id.

So if you would have stored the `user_id` in the `user_task` table instead of `email` the queries would have looked like

```
select
u.id as user_id,
u.email,
ut.task_id,
t.name
from user_task ut
join user u on u._id = ut.user_id
join tasks t on t._id = ut.task_id
where u.email = 'some email id'
```

and

```
select  
u._id as user_id,
u.email,
ut.task_id,
t.name as task_name,
st._id as sub_task_id,
st.name as sub_task_name
from subtask st
join tasks t on t._id = st.task_id
join user_task ut on ut.task_id = t._id
join user u on u._id = ut.user_id
where u.email = 'some email id'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" 
INNER JOIN "user_tasks" ON "user_tasks"."task_id" = "tasks"."id" 
INNER JOIN "subtask" ON "subtask"."task_id" = "tasks"."id"
```

You can change `INNER JOIN` to `OUTER JOIN` and manipulate the data sets by using Joins

See here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try with INNER JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks T
INNER JOIN user_tasks UT ON T._id = UT.task_id
WHERE UT.email='$email'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tasks tsk INNER JOIN user_tasks usr_tsk ON tsk._id = usr_tsk.task_id WHERE usr_tsk.email='$email';